# Removing page from navigation stack when tab selected

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI Shell app, I have a structure like this:

- Page 1 (Shell Tab)
- Page 2 (Shell Tab)

  - Page 2a (Detail Page)
- Page 3 (Shell Tab)

If I navigate as follows:

Page 2 > Page 2a > Page 3 > Page 2

I actually end up on Page 2a and not Page 2.

In other words, going to a tab page doesn’t remove previous detail pages from navigation stack.

I’m not suggesting this is wrong or an error but I’d like to remove previous detail pages from navigation stack every time I tap on a page on tab bar.

How do I achieve this? There must be some method that I can override to get into the navigation process to add my business logic.

Answer (score 0):

You may override AppShell `OnNavigating` method, which is called when the Navigating event fires.

And you may try the following code as a workaround,

Suppose DetailPage was registered in AppShell.cs,

```
    Routing.RegisterRoute("detail", typeof(DetailPage));
```

And we could override OnNavigating method to remove the DetailPage in the stack,

```
    protected override void OnNavigating(ShellNavigatingEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigating(args);
        var stack = Shell.Current?.Navigation.NavigationStack.ToArray();
        int count = stack?.Length ?? 0;

        if (stack != null)
        {
            if (args.Current.Location.OriginalString == "//Page2/detail" && args.Target.Location.OriginalString!= "//Page2"  )
            {
                Shell.Current.Navigation.RemovePage(stack[count - 1]);
            }

        }

    }
```

Hope it helps!